# LWJGL: Unable to draw textures using nvidia gpu

Tags: java, opengl, nvidia, lwjgl, glfw

So we're developing a simple game in Java using LWJGL with GLFW and OpenGL 3.3.

On AMD and Intel it works perfectly but on Nvidia it doesn't. The screen is just black (the value from glClearColor), there are neither Java-exceptions nor OpenGL-Errors.

What are we doing wrong?

Main.java:

```java
public class Main {
    Shader defaultShader;
    boolean running = false;
    long window;
    int width = 1000;
    int height = 1000;
    String title = "pain";
    int vao;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        var pain = new Pain();
        pain.init();
        pain.run();
    }

    public void init() throws RuntimeException {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if (!glfwInit()) throw new RuntimeException("glfw.init.failed");

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

        this.window = glfwCreateWindow(this.width, this.height, this.title, 0, 0);
        if (window == NULL) throw new RuntimeException("glfw.window.failed");

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        this.vao = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        this.defaultShader = new Shader("main");

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void run() {
        this.running = true;
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

        ByteBuffer data = null;
        try {
            data = stbi_load_from_memory(BufferCreator.createByteBuffer(FileHandler.readFileAsBytes("fuckoff/" + "heal_powerup.png")), width, height, comp, 4);
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        if (data == null) throw new RuntimeException("texture.load.failed");

        int id = glGenTextures();
        int twidth = width.get();
        int theight = height.get();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, twidth, theight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        stbi_image_free(data);

        int vid;
        int tid;
        int dc;
        int arg4;
        int[] indices = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0};
        dc = indices.length;

        vid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vid);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferCreator.createFloatBuffer(new float[]{
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                100.0f, 0.0f,
                100.0f, 100.0f,
                0.0f, 100.0f
        }), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        arg4 = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, arg4);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferCreator.createIntBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        tid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tid);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferCreator.createFloatBuffer(new float[]{
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f
        }), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



        while(this.running) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            defaultShader.bind();

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
            this.defaultShader.setUniform("sampler", 0);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vid);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tid);
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, arg4);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, dc, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


            //Unbind buffers
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            //Disable
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) shutdown();
            System.out.println(glGetError());
        }

        glfwFreeCallbacks(this.window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(this.window);
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    void shutdown(){
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

Shader.java:

```java
public class Shader {
    private int program, vs, fs;

    public Shader(String name) {
        try {
            this.program = glCreateProgram();

            this.vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(this.vs, FileHandler.readFile("shaders/" + name + ".vs"));
            glCompileShader(this.vs);
            if (glGetShaderi(this.vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) throw new RuntimeException("shader.compile.failed\n" + glGetShaderInfoLog(vs));

            this.fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(this.fs, FileHandler.readFile("shaders/" + name + ".fs"));
            glCompileShader(this.fs);
            if (glGetShaderi(this.fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != 1) throw new RuntimeException("shader.compile.failed" + glGetShaderInfoLog(fs));

            glAttachShader(this.program, this.vs);
            glAttachShader(this.program, this.fs);

            glBindAttribLocation(this.program, 0, "vertices");
            glBindAttribLocation(this.program, 1, "textures");

            glLinkProgram(this.program);
            if (glGetProgrami(this.program, GL_LINK_STATUS) != 1) throw new RuntimeException("shader.link.failed");
            glValidateProgram(this.program);
            if (glGetProgrami(this.program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) != 1) throw new RuntimeException("shader.validation.failed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void updateShaderParameters() {
        this.setUniform("sampler", 0);
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(this.program, "windowSize");
        if (location != 1) {
            glUniform2f(location, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, int value) {
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(this.program, name);
        if (location != -1) {
            glUniform1i(location, value);
        }
    }

    public void bind() {
        glUseProgram(this.program);
        this.updateShaderParameters();
    }
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertices;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 textures;

uniform vec2 windowSize;

out vec2 tex_coords;

void main() {
    tex_coords = textures;
    gl_Position = vec4(2.0/windowSize.x * vertices.x - 1.0, (2.0/windowSize.y * vertices.y - 1.0) * -1.0, 1, 1);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D sampler;

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 tex_coords;

void main() {
    if (texture(sampler, tex_coords).a != 1.0f) {
        discard;
    }

    FragColor = texture(sampler, tex_coords);
}
```

BufferCreator.java and FileHandler.java are simple utility-classes which seem to work perfectly.

I assume, it has something to do with the Sampler because when I remove the if...discard statement in the Fragment Shader and set FragColor to some random values, it is drawn.

Comment: Did you check if the object get's rendered when you output a constant color? That would at least give some hints whether the texture is the problem or if the geometry isn't there.

Comment: Yes, I did. When I use vec4 in the Fragment Shader and remove the if-statement, it works. Looks like the problem hast something to do with the sampler2d.

Comment: Or with the if... discard statement. I don't know what exact data your texture contains, but maybe try something like `if (texture(sampler, tex_coords).a <= 0.98)`. Also note that it would be a huge performance improvement if you query the texture only once instead of twice.

Comment: So, when I just remove the if... discard statement, the texture should be drawn with black background instead of transparency (because I do not use blend). That's how it is on AMD and Intel, but on Nvidia it's only black. That's why I assume, that the problem has to do something with the sampler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updateShaderParameters() method your checking for `!=1` it should be `!=-1` since windowSize location would be 1. 
 If your checking for 1, it will never get set. 
This could be an oversight or a mistype at the end. Happens to the best of us.

```
public void updateShaderParameters() {
        this.setUniform("sampler", 0);
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(this.program, "windowSize");
        if (location != -1) {
            glUniform2f(location, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }
```